# Exception handling in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to create a new filter where I throw an `AuthenticationException` in the `doFilter` method's body

```
public void doFilter(...){
     if( something )
     {
        throw new AuthenticationException("...");
     }
}
```

How can I handle this exception to avoid the `Server Error` from storefront in case that the exception is thrown? Is there something like `@ControllerAdvice` from Spring?

Comment: Which Hybris Version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set response http status instead of returning exceptions.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
  final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
  httpServletResponse.setStatus(401);
  httpServletResponse.sendError(401);
  httpServletResponse.getWriter().write("401 Authentication needed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only to make this clear, there are multiple possibilities how doing 'Exception Handling' in a Spring project. Here is a very good documentation from baeldung about the different solutions. [baeldung-link](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring)

Now you ask explicit for 'best was in Hybris'. I would say there there is none. Hybris only throws the exceptions. Have a look at the `BaseSiteMismatchException` that is thrown in the `BaseSiteCheckFilter`. And now it is your decision if and how to handle those.

But mainly the question is, why you want to use an exception here? Wouldn't it make more sense to set the response status to `401`?